# How to set specific font for the first paragraph in every chapter/section

Tags: fonts, listings, paragraphs, everypar

I need to have the first paragraph typeset with a different font in every chapter and section and I don't want this to affect `\lstlisting`. I tried to use `\everypar` but if `\lstlisting` is there it breaks. How can I do this?

Comment: Please write a minimal working example.

Comment: Be aware that LaTeX invokes `\par` at places you would not suspect, so using `\everpar` can lead to unexpected consequences.

Comment: The used class (and if used any package mangling with the code for headings) is an important information that is strictly needed to to provide some working code. So please, provide a minimal working example that includes every headings related information of your document and a small example with cases where things should work and notable exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works with the standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`). It utilizes the new hooks introduced with recent LaTeX versions.

You might need to handle exceptions yourself, at least for simple stuff like in the following example everything works out.

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\usepackage{listings}

% change this for your setup, restoreparformat should revert all the changes you
% introduce with firstparformat
\newcommand*\firstparformat  {\sffamily\large}
\newcommand*\restoreparformat{\rmfamily\normalsize}

% this injects the code into the hooks
% ------------------------------------
% changes should be global (just to make sure), hence we don't use `\newif`
\let\iffirstparformat\iffalse
\protected\def\firstparformatfalse{\global\let\iffirstparformat\iffalse}
\protected\def\firstparformattrue {\global\let\iffirstparformat\iftrue}
% sections are a hard thing, there are subsections and stuff all using the same
% internals
\protected\def\startsectionsaveform
  {%
    \global\let\startsectionsaveformTMP\iffirstparformat
    \firstparformatfalse
  }
\protected\def\startsectionrestoreform
  {\global\let\iffirstparformat\startsectionsaveformTMP}
\AddToHook{cmd/section/before}       {\firstparformattrue}
\AddToHook{cmd/@startsection/before} {\startsectionsaveform}
\AddToHook{cmd/@xsect/after}         {\startsectionrestoreform}
% chapters are way easier
\AddToHook{cmd/chapter/before}       {\firstparformatfalse}
\AddToHook{cmd/@chapter/after}       {\firstparformattrue}
\AddToHook{cmd/@schapter/after}      {\firstparformattrue}
% the paragraphs check whether they are the first and if so use the format
\AddToHook{para/begin}
  {%
    \iffirstparformat
      \expandafter\firstparformat
    \fi
  }
% at the end of the paragraph we might need to revert these changes
\AddToHook{para/after}
  {%
    \iffirstparformat
      \firstparformatfalse
      \expandafter\restoreparformat
    \fi
  }

% exceptions
\AddToHook{env/lstlisting/before}{\firstparformatfalse}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\blindduck[1-2]
\section{Section}
\blindduck[1-2]
\subsection{Subsection}
\blindduck[1-2]

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\blindduck[1-2]
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{lstlisting}
listing
listing
\listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]